# Is there a way to test if two separate values, in two separate arrays, and check if they are equal or not?

Tags: python-3.x

Im trying to see if a value in one array is equal to that in another array, the values are integer values.

Ive tried turning them into string and integers from the array but get the error that they cannot be converted implicitly.

```py
winningnumber = []
usernumber = []

print(winningnumber)
print(usernumber)

if(winningnumber == usernumber):
   print("Exact number")
```

I would then get an output like so

[1]

['1']

Comment: Are the values in each array always going to be in the same spot? Or is it a matter of if the value in one array appears in the other at all?

Comment: The values will always be the first in the array, and just whether the value of each array is exactly equal

Comment: Answer posted. @Blake Cook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this, what you want to do is access the first item of each array, and compare that value.

There are a lot of ways to do this, but here is a little driver program to show you one way.

```
# Defining a function to see if they match
def is_winning(arr1, arr2):
    # Grabbing the first element in each array
    # denoted by the [0], for the "0th" element
    arr1_first_ele = arr1[0]
    arr2_first_ele = arr2[0]

    # If the first element in the first array matches the first element in the second
    if arr1_first_ele == arr2_first_ele:
        # Print out they match
        print("They match")
    # Otherwise
    else:
        # Print out that they dont
        print("They don't match")

def main():
    # Example arrays
    test_array_one = [1,3,4]
    test_array_two = [5,4,3]
    # This should print out "They don't match"
    is_winning(test_array_one, test_array_two)

    # Example arrays
    test_array_three = [6,7,8]
    test_array_four = [6,5,4]
    # This should print out "They match"
    is_winning(test_array_three, test_array_four)

main()
```

This evaluates to:

They don't match 
They match

Comment: Ok this helps me alot, in that the 0th element 6,6 in test arrays three and four match, and the others they dont match. That makes sense. Thank you for the fast response

Comment: @BlakeCook exactly correct. It is no problem. You can thank us by accepting this answer as correct so future users can use it too. Feel free to post and try to answer questions and become a part of the community :)

Comment: @BlakeCook please don't forget to mark this as correct.

Comment: i need at least 15 reputation before i can upvote or downvote.

Comment: You shouldnt need to vote, simply click the check mark to mark as correct =) @BlakeCook